# Convert VM (redhat virtualization 3.5) to a physical server

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, ovirt

I have a virtual machine running on red hat virtualization 3.5, i need to convert that VM to a physical server. (mainly due to a performance issue)

my volume groups as follows

```
NAME                                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
vda                                  252:0    0   100G  0 disk
├─vda1                               252:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
└─vda2                               252:2    0  99.5G  0 part
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_root (dm-0)       253:0    0     4G  0 lvm  /
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_swap (dm-1)       253:1    0     8G  0 lvm
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_home (dm-3)       253:3    0     4G  0 lvm  /home
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_usr (dm-4)        253:4    0     4G  0 lvm  /usr
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_tmp (dm-5)        253:5    0     4G  0 lvm  /tmp
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_opt (dm-6)        253:6    0     4G  0 lvm  /opt
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_var (dm-7)        253:7    0     4G  0 lvm  /var
├─vg_volgrp01-lv_var_log (dm-8)    253:8    0     4G  0 lvm  /var/log
└─vg_volgrp01-lv_opt_imail (dm-9)  253:9    0  63.5G  0 lvm  /opt/imail
vdb                                  252:16   0   1.1T  0 disk
└─vg_volgrp02-lv_data_indexes (dm-2) 253:2    0   1.1T  0 lvm         /data/indexes
   sda                                    8:0    0 446.1G  0 disk
└   ─vg_volgrp03-lv_data_SSD (dm-10)    253:10   0 446.1G  0 lvm     /data/SSD
```

there are tools to convert p2v, v2p for vmware environment , but couldn't find any tool to do the task for RHEVM platform.

appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Isn't it an option just to simply dd your VM to a physical server? Couldn't that work? I'm pretty sure there will be some issues with the network cards (I've done simple dd between servers and the NIC were messed up) but after fixing those, then I think the server should work fine.